# Matrix Data Type in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is there a data type called Matrix in C++?

If Yes, which header file should be included for using it?

Answer (score 3):

The [Boost Matrix Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm) provides this. For higher numbers of dimensions, the [Boost Multidimensional Array Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) is also available.

Full examples are available on the documentation pages.

Comment: Boost matrix uses dynamic allocations, if yorue looking for at fast matrix implementation of static size, take a look at something like http://www.geometrictools.com/LibMathematics/Algebra/Wm5Matrix4.inl

Answer (score 2):

[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is another option.

Answer (score 0):

[Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) is also a good option. Very easy to use: its syntax is similar to Matlab.